# Excercise about C lists

Tags: c, list, linked-list

I need help with the following code about linked lists:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct nodo {
    int d;
    struct nodo *next;
};

struct nodo *full();

int main()
{
    struct nodo *l;
    /* l=(struct nodo *)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo)); */
    l = full();
    while(l!=NULL) {
        printf("-->%d\n", l->d);
        l  =l->next;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
struct nodo *full()
{
    int i;
    struct nodo *head, *nes;
    head = (struct nodo *)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    head->next = NULL;
    for(i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        nes = (struct nodo *)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
        printf("Insert the %d element:\n", i);
        scanf("%d", &nes->d);
        nes->next = head;
        head = nes;
    }
    return head;
}
```

If I try for example to input `1, 2, 3, 4`, I get the following output:

```
 -->4
 -->3
 -->2
 -->1
 -->9708864
```

Why do I get the last number? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Is this homework? Also: 1. no need to cast the result of `malloc`, 2. no need to `malloc` before calling `full()`, 3. You're not calling `free()`...

Comment: @EitanT of course it is; if it wasn't, OP wouldn't have dared to cast the return value of malloc().

Comment: @EitanT I always cast the result of malloc because yes,it is an homework and plus if I don't cast,my compiler returns this error: invalid conversion from `void*' to `nodo*' Where should i call free?

Comment: @wild91 what kind of crappy C compiler is yours? void * **must** be implicitly compatible with any pointer type.

Comment: @H2CO3 I resolved this "issue",I was saving this file as .cpp and not as .c,my bad:)Anyway I am using dev-c++ on Windows 7.

Comment: @wild91 Maybe you're compiling with a C++ compiler? `void*` doesn't need to be cast to another pointer. Also, I've taken the liberty to format your code. Next time tag it as [tag: homework].

Comment: I suggest that this is an excellent opportunity to become acquainted with the use of your friendly neighborhood symbolic debugger.  The problem here is not difficult to diagnose, but if we tell you the answer nobody wins, most especially not you.  Suck it up, dive in, and work through it yourself.  Good luck.

Comment: @EitanT Yes I was compiling filename.cpp and not filename.c. My bad.

Comment: It seems to me that one extra uninitialized element gets created at full(). Or are my (sleepy) eyes mistaking me?

Comment: Without actually taking the time to look at your code, behavior of that nature often occurs when you're reading a value that you haven't initialized, and thus the information in that value will be complete garbage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Vinska pointed out in the comments, line 3 of `full()` is not necessary; it is creating an extra node.

The line in question is

`head = (struct nodo *)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));`

Instead, say

`head = NULL`

With your existing code, your linked list has 5 elements. The first one is created on the aforementioned line. The remaining four items are created in the loop, as expected, for a total of 5 elements.

The `9708864` number is a garbage value. It is whatever happened to be in memory when you called `malloc()`. This is why you have to initialize all of your variables! Or, in this case, use `memset()` or `calloc()` to set those blocks to some sane value. (However, that line is completely superfluous here anyway.)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I do not see that you are preserving the start of the linked list. I would do this:

```
struct nodo *full()
{
    int i;
    struct nodo *head, *nes;
    head = (struct nodo *)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    nes = head;

    for(i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        nes->next = (struct nodo *)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
        printf("Insert the %d element:", i);
        scanf("%d", &nes->d);
        printf("%s","\n");
        nes = nes->next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

This creates the head of the list, but then uses your "running" or "current" list pointer -- nes -- as the list creator.

While you are creating the list, head remains pointed to the head of the list.

I made another modification, so that the line terminator happens after you've entered the number.